# GWT + Maven + Eclipse -> Easy way?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, mojo

I want to set up a GWT Project with Maven. Now I am wondering what would be the easiest way to do so?

I stumbled over the Mojo GWT Maven plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin. But this looks rather complicated to set up.

Now my questions:

1. Is there an easier way to set up a GWT Maven Project?
2. Do I necessarily need another GWT Maven plugin (expect the normal Maven plugin of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not really. GWT projects are inherently complicated since they're using a different compiler with different rules. Feel free to clarify with more specific questions about it.
2. I don't know what you mean by "normal Maven plugin", but you do need `gwt-maven-plugin` attached to at least your final `war` project so that the appropriate Javascript files get generated.

Comment: A specific question would be: How do I actually install the Mojo GWT Maven plugin in elcipse? Do I just need to specify it in my pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. m2e will automatically scan your POM and pull in extra plugins. You may have to add lifecycle bindings depending on all your versions; Eclipse will tell you if so.

Answer (score 0):

Running the sample project with the plugin you mentioned is actually quite easy if you are willing to do it from command-line only. Then you can modify it according to you. Maybe later integrate to Eclipse if you understand it more. 
See my post in this thread:
[How to deploy in a gwt-maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113333/how-to-deploy-in-a-gwt-maven-project/18114596#18114596)

Answer (score 0):

Use the archetype provided by the [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html); it is better to stick with Maven than manually package the WAR file.